# Assimp compilation errors Win10 + Visual studio 2017 community

Tags: assimp

I can't get assimp compiled on my laptop (Windows 10, Visual studio 2017 community). Everything compiles nice on my work PC.

I just clone repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/assimp/assimp.git
cd assimp
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

here out of cmake command

```
    -- Building for: Visual Studio 15 2017
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.14.26428.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.14.26428.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.14.26428/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.14.26428/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.14.26428/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.14.26428/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Shared libraries enabled
-- Looking for DirectX...
-- DirectX_PREFIX_PATH changed.
-- Could not locate DirectX
-- Looking for ZLIB...
-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
-- Could not locate ZLIB
-- compiling zlib from souces
CMake Deprecation Warning at contrib/zlib/CMakeLists.txt:8 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0048 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of off64_t
-- Check size of off64_t - failed
-- Looking for fseeko
-- Looking for fseeko - not found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - not found
-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
-- Could NOT find rt (missing: RT_LIBRARY)
-- Enabled formats: AMF 3DS AC ASE ASSBIN ASSXML B3D BVH COLLADA DXF CSM HMP IRRMESH IRR LWO LWS MD2 MD3 MD5 MDC MDL NFF NDO OFF OBJ OGRE OPENGEX PLY MS3D COB BLEND IFC XGL FBX Q3D Q3BSP RAW SIB SMD STL TERRAGEN 3D X X3D GLTF 3MF MMD
-- Disabled formats:
-- Could NOT find IL (missing: IL_LIBRARIES IL_INCLUDE_DIR)
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:439 (MESSAGE):
  Build of assimp_qt_viewer is disabled.  Unsatisfied dendencies: Qt5 DevIL


-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to:
```

this makes solution for my Visual studio, which I'm trying to build using Build All menu. I get following errors:

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2065   'AI_IMPORT_IFC_DEFAULT_SMOOTHING_ANGLE': undeclared identifier  assimp
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "AI_CONFIG_GLOBAL_SCALE_FACTOR_KEY" is undefined assimp
Error   C2065   'AI_CONFIG_GLOBAL_SCALE_FACTOR_KEY': undeclared identifier  assimp
```

But if I try to navigate to this define - Intellisense allow me to do this. I see this defines. What am I doing wrong, please help?

Comment: Use release revision, i.e. `git fetch origin 80799bdbf90ce626475635815ee18537718a05b1 && git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD` or simply download release source code archive from https://github.com/assimp/assimp/releases

Comment: Tried with no luck :( Same errors: ifcloader.cpp(162): error C2065: 'AI_CONFIG_IMPORT_IFC_SMOOTHING_ANGLE': undeclared identifier

Comment: Ok, I found that something wrong with compile-time generated defines. There are two files with defines - one from source dir, one from cmake build dir. And one does not contain defines which cause this error...

Comment: I dig deeper - there are these two config.h files: one from ./include/assimp/config.h and one from {build_dir}/include/config.h (this one copied from config.h.in. And it seems that wrong config files used when it included with #include <assimp/config.h>. I tried to rename file from source directory (to force usage of copied file) and everything compiled - build all succeeded (but1477 warnings)

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out. I will try to fix that on the current master.